# How to assign an textedit value to a float variable in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, var

very newbie in Android Studio Kotlin and am struggling to pass a value from an edittext object to a float variable, but it is proving to be a challenge. I was able to do it but only after making use of 2 additional variables; however I can't believe it can't be done directly.
This is how I managed to do it:

```
        var temp: EditText = findViewById(R.id.txtPriceA)
        var temp2: String  = temp.getText().toString()
        var priceA: Float = temp2.toFloat()
```

The XML for the edittext is this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPriceA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/enter_price_a"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="#0E0B0B"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        tools:text="$23.45" />
```

I thank you all in advance for any help.
Ray.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the intermediate variable like so:

```kotlin
val priceA = findViewById(R.id.txtPriceA).getText().toString().toFloat()
```

If you are just getting started, and only getting the hang of the framework you should consider this as the only way.

After you got the hang of things I think you should take a look at viewmodels and databinding, that way you will be able to write an inverse binding adapter that would map the value of the text field to a variable in your viewmodel as a float directly.

As you get more comfortable with kotlin, you could also write an extension property for this purpose. Combined with kotlin synthetic view binding your code could look like this:

```kotlin
val priceA = txtPriceA.floatValue
```

Good luck with your android endeavors!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This will probably not the only time I ask for help. :)

Comment: I tried that and I get an error. The 'findViewById' is red underlined and hovering over it, it reads 'Not enough information to infer type variable T'; and there is a compilation error.

Comment: I found the answer: val priceA: Float = txtPriceA.text.toString().toFloat()